# Java: Queue with expiration mechanism

Tags: java, android, queue

I am building an Android app which sends regular updates to a server.

When the internet is disconnected, I would like to store these events and send them to the server when the connection is resumed. The trivial mechanism for storing this type of events is a Queue.

However, after a given amount of time, events age and are no longer relevant. Therefore, I would like the Queue to automatically delete items after a given amount of time.

**Is there a Java Queue which auto-deletes items that were not dequeued after a given time?**

### Notes

- The [DelayQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html) mechanism in Java provides the reverse behaviour - items can not be dequeued before a given amount of time has passed.
- Developing such a Queue is not a very big deal, but a stable existing solution is always preferred.

Comment: How old should it be to not be relevant anymore? If you're talking about anything longer than a few seconds, you should probably store it in SQLite and while looping through the cursor check the age before sending the data. I'm suggest that, because nothing guarantee that the VM will still run after the activity is closed and anything stored in RAM will be gone.